# Execute function IF another function is complete NOT when

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having trouble creating a slider that pauses on hover, because I execute the animation function again on mouse off, if I flick the mouse over it rapidly (thereby calling the function multiple times) it starts to play up, I would like it so that the function is only called if the other function is complete, otherwise it does not call at all (to avoid queue build up and messy animations)

What's the easiest/best way to do this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//get variables
var slide_width      = $('.slider_container').width();
var number_of_slides = $('.slider_container .slide').length;
var slider_width = slide_width*number_of_slides;

//set element dimensions
$('.slide').width(slide_width);
$('.slider').width(slider_width);

var n = 1;

$('.slider_container').hover(function() { 
//Mouse on
    n = 0;
    $('.slider').stop(true, false);
}, function() {
//Mouse off
    n = 1;
    if (fnct == 0) sliderLoop();
});

//Called in Slide Loop
function animateSlider() {
        $('.slider').delay(3000).animate({ marginLeft: -(slide_width * i) }, function() {
            i++;
            sliderLoop();
        });


}

var i = 0;

var fnct = 0

//Called in Doc Load
function sliderLoop() {
    fnct = 1
    if(n == 1) {
        if (i < number_of_slides) {
            animateSlider();
        }
        else
        {
            i = 0;
            sliderLoop();
        }
    }
    fnct = 0
}

sliderLoop();


});
```

The slider works fine normally, but if I quickly move my mouse on and off it, then the slider starts jolting back and forth rapidly...been trying to come up with a solution for this for hours now..

Comment: It sounds like you need to add `.stop(true)` to your animation calls. Can you show your code please.

Comment: stop works to kill the animation, but not the entire function I believe? give me a second and ill post my code.

Comment: `function animateSlider() {
    $('.slider').delay(3000).stop(true).animate({ marginLeft: -(slide_width * i) }, function() {
        i++;
        sliderLoop();
    });
}`

Comment: using stop in conjunction with delay seems to eliminate the delay completely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what fixed it, works a charm!

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//get variables
var slide_width = $('.slider_container').width();
var number_of_slides = $('.slider_container .slide').length;
var slider_width = slide_width*number_of_slides;

//set element dimensions
$('.slide').width(slide_width);
$('.slider').width(slider_width);

var n = 1;
var t = 0;
$('.slider_container').hover(function() { 
    clearInterval(t);
    }, function() {
    t = setInterval(sliderLoop,3000);
});

var marginSize = i = 1;
var fnctcmp = 0;


//Called in Doc Load
function sliderLoop() {
if (i < number_of_slides) {
marginSize = -(slide_width * i++);
}
else
{
marginSize = i = 1;
}

$('.slider').animate({ marginLeft: marginSize });   
}


t = setInterval(sliderLoop,3000);

});
```